# Cordova build removes my /res/ -images

Tags: cordova, build

Since I updated from Cordova 3.6 to 5.4.0, I am somehow losing my splash screen images at the build process.

I have all my images in ./platforms/android/res/drawable<-resolution>/

As soon as I call `cordova build android --release` it first removes all my png files (not the folders, just the files) and then rises an error for each file missing but referenced in my config.xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My fault. Cordova fetches the images from the location referenced in the config.xml. Before it does so, it removes all images from ./platforms/android/res/

I accidentally deleted my source images folder - and I did not recognize that the path in the config.xml is different from ./platforms/android/res/ (which is ok, but there need to be the same images/structure there).